# Scala future for comprehension chain futures and results

Tags: scala, asynchronous, functional-programming

I want to execute the func method with each method call having the result from the previous and returning the final method value.

Is there a way I can make it less verbose and dynamic so that if I have to do this 100+ times I don't end up having 100 lines?

```
    val a : Future[String] = for {
      comp1Result <- Future { func(shopRequest) }
      comp2Result <- Future { func(comp1Result) }
      comp3Result <- Future { func(comp2Result) }
      comp4Result <- Future { func(comp3Result) }
      comp5Result <- Future { func(comp4Result) }
      comp6Result <- Future { func(comp5Result) }
      comp7Result <- Future { func(comp6Result) }
      comp8Result <- Future { func(comp7Result) }
      comp9Result <- Future { func(comp8Result) }
      comp10Result <- Future { func(comp9Result) }
      comp11Result <- Future { func(comp10Result) }
      comp12Result <- Future { func(comp11Result) }
      comp13Result <- Future { func(comp12Result) }
      comp14Result <- Future { func(comp13Result) }
      comp15Result <- Future { func(comp14Result) }
      comp16Result <- Future { func(comp15Result) }
      comp17Result <- Future { func(comp16Result) }
    } yield {comp17Result }
```

Comment: I guess you need recursion function with a counter, so it can stop on in 17th call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a simple tail-recursive method to repetitively chain `Future{ func(result) }` via `flatMap` for a given number of times:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def func(s: String): String = ???

@scala.annotation.tailrec
def loopFutures(future: Future[String], n: Int): Future[String] = n match {
  case 1 => future
  case _ => loopFutures(future.flatMap(r => Future{ func(r) }), n - 1)
}
```

For example, to use method `loopFutures` to perform your `for-comprehension`:

```
loopFutures(Future{ func(shopRequest) }, 17)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in performing each computation in a `Future`, it is simpler to perform all the computations in one `Future`. Then a simple `foldLeft` operation can be used:

```
Future((1 to 17).foldLeft(shopRequest) { case (r, _) => func(r) })
```

If you do want to create a `Future` each time, it looks like this:

```
(1 to 17).foldLeft(Future.successful(shopRequest)) {
  case (r, _) => r.flatMap(x => Future(func(x)))
}
```

Comment: Nice one, Tim! the flatMap in the second example could be changed to a map:
case (r, _) => r map func